How to connect multiple authenticated clients' with Django channels and clients should be connected before opening the channels?
So I'm working on a desktop based app that requires a socket to handle multiple authenticated clients with a Django channel, and clients should be authenticated by the server before opening the channels. The server is running on one different system, and clients are connecting to multiple systems. I have tried to connect a socket with a different platform with much effort, but I have failed to connect it. Is it possible to connect clients on different platforms to the server? If yes, please help me to resolve this issue because I am new to this technology.
My question: is using the code below, how would I be able to have multiple clients connected? I have tried lists, but I just can't figure out the format for them. How can I accomplished this where multiple clients are connected to Websocket, and l am able to send data to a specific or multiple clients? and how can I add channels in the below code?
I need your valuable suggestions or feedback would be highly appreciated.
server.py

import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8080))

serversocket.listen(10)  # become a server socket connections

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(64)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print(buf)
        break

Here is the client script, I don't want to send data using an API any other way to get data from the server side:

client.py
def register_user():
    username = reg_username_entry.get()
    password = reg_password_entry.get()
    if not username or not password:
        messagebox.showerror("Input Error", "Please enter a username and password.")
        return

    data = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }

    try:
        response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register/", json=data)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", response.json()['success'])
        else:
            try:
                error_message = response.json().get('error', 'Registration failed')
            except ValueError:
                error_message = response.text
            messagebox.showerror("Error", error_message)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Request failed", str(e))


def login_user():
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

    username = login_username_entry.get()
    password = login_password_entry.get()
    if not username or not password:
        messagebox.showerror("Input Error", "Please enter a username and password.")
        return

    data = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password
    }

    try:
        response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/", json=data)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", response.json()['success'])
            # messagebox.showinfo("Message", "Hey There! I hope you are doing well.")
            clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8080))
            clientsocket.send(bytes('Socket Connected!', 'utf-8'))
            print(f"Hostname: {hostname}")
            print(f"IP Address: {ip_address}")

        else:
            try:
                error_message = response.json().get('error', 'Login failed')
            except ValueError:
                error_message = response.text
            messagebox.showerror("Error", error_message)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Request failed", str(e))


You said you are using Django Channels but you aren’t. You are using Python’s built-in socket library.

Hello sir , The given code is my simple client-server code. I am not using a channel, but now I want to connect the client and server using a channel on different platforms for client connectivity. How can I do it?

You say things like: "… using the code below, how would I be able to have multiple clients connected?" and things like: "Websocket". I hope you know what you are doing but I can’t answer your question because it lacks clarity.
